# Is there a fast algorithm to determine the largest multiplicity of the eigenvalues of Hermitian matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

What is the fastest way to determine the largest multiplicity of the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$? What if $A$ was real? I am thinking that the only way of doing this is to form the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Are there shortcuts for small matrices, say $n\leq4$?

**Background**

I am trying to implement Algorithm 2 in [1], which is a revised Lanczos’ process. It is used to tridiagonalize $A$ so that its spectra can be determined by means of implicit QR decomposition.

[1]: [Xu et al. (2023): Fast algorithms for singular value decomposition and the inverse of nearly low-rank matrices](https://doi.org/10.1093/nsr/nwad083)

Comment: Multiplicity does not really exist in numerical methods, especially in floating-point algorithms. Eigenvalues of multiplicity $m$ resolve into clusters of diameter $\sim\mu^{1/m}$ under the first such operation, usually the transformation to Hessenberg form, which for symmetric or Hermitian matrices gives a tridiagonal result. So what you need is to search for clusters of eigenvalues

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think the best way is to compute the characteristic polynomial and to compute inductively on $k$, $P_k = \chi_A \wedge \chi_A' \wedge \cdots \wedge \chi_A^{(k)}$. If $k_0$ is the smallest integer such that $P_{k_0} = 1$, then the maximal multiplicity is $k_0 - 1$ (and you did all this without factorisation/diagonalisation/trigonalisation so it is not too long).

Let $m$ be the maximal multiplicity of the eigenvalues of $A$. Computing $\chi_A$ takes $\mathrm{O}(M(n))$ operations where $M(n)$ is the number of operations you need to multiply two $n \times n$ matrices (see https://www.wlkl.ch/myPdfs/fastCharacteristicPolynomial.pdf). Then, computing $P_{k + 1}$ from $P_k$ takes $\mathrm{O}(\min(\deg(P_k),\deg(\chi_A^{(k)})))$ with Euclid's algorithm. This is bounded by $n - k$ and computing the derivatives of a polynomial is linear in its degree. Finally, the complexity is,
$$
C(n,m) = \mathrm{O}\!\left(M(n) + \sum_{k = 1}^m n - k\right) = \mathrm{O}(M(n) + mn - m(m + 1)/2).
$$
And if you want a bound that is uniform with respect to $m$, the worst case is when $m = n$ (or at least when it is close to $n$) and
$$
C(n) = \mathrm{O}(M(n) + n^2 - n(n + 1)/2) = \mathrm{O}(n^2).
$$

For small matrices, you have the following (partial) results,

$*$ For $n = 2$, $m = 1$ unless $A$ is a homothety because Hermitian matrices are diagonalisable.

$*$ For $n = 3$, $m \leqslant 2$ unless $m$ is a homothety (the same argument holds for any $n$) and in this case, $m = 2$ if and only if $\Delta(\chi_A) = 0$ where $\Delta(X^3 + bX^2 + cX + d) = -4b^3d + b^2c^2 + 18bcd - 4c^3 - 27d^2$ is the discriminant of $\chi_A$.

$*$ For $n = 4$, I don't see a short way to distinguish $m = 2$ and $m = 3$ once you found that $m$ is not a homothety and $\Delta(\chi_A) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am, however, unfamiliar with the wedge notation in this context. What does $\chi_A \wedge \chi_A' \wedge \cdots \wedge \chi_A^{(k)}$ mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is the GCD ! $P_{k + 1} = P_k \wedge \chi_A^{(k + 1)} = GCD(P_k,\chi_A^{(k + 1)})$ and $P_0 = \chi_A$.